# Dynamic [ NotebookEvaluate ["_"] ]

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, notebooks, scheduling

A nice way to centralize various tasks in one notebook is the `NotebookEvaluation` function. For instance I can evaluate ten notebooks from a single notebook (e.g. allnotebooks.nb) like this:

```
NotebookEvaluation["nbpath_1.nb"]
NotebookEvaluation["nbpath_2.nb"]
...
NotebookEvaluation["nbpath_10.nb"]
```

I would like to update this automatically, e.g. every six hours, but it doesnt work. My idea is to create a master notebook with the following code (here: 15 seconds):

```
Dynamic[NotebookEvaluate[
  "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\allnotebooks.nb"], 
 UpdateInterval -> 15]
```

And it works without using dynamic. Using dynamic gives the following error:

> ```
> An unknown box name (ToBoxes) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression.
> Check the format rules for the expression.
> ```

Does someone have an idea about the reason? Is `Dynamic` not an adequate function to do this?

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

P.S. I tested it with this code for the sub notebooks, e.g. for nbpath_1.nb:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\";
time = DateString[{"YearShort", "Month", "Day", "_", "Hour", "Minute",
     "Second"}];
data = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 10}], {10}];
Export[path <> "nb1_" <> time <> ".xls", data];
```

Comment: I think you can check `ScheduledTasks` to manage repeated evaluation easily.

Comment: `ScheduledTasks` is more appropriate. `Dynamic` is for display. You could try `Dynamic[NotebookEvaluate[
  "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\allnotebooks.nb"];ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 
 UpdateInterval -> 15]`

Comment: ScheduledTasks works perfectly. Especially the RunScheduledTask option. Thanks a lot for your help! Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record:

[`ScheduledTasks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RunScheduledTask.html?q=RunScheduledTask&lang=en) will be more convenient to manage this task. Just like:

```
RunScheduledTask[Print@DateList[], {3, 2}]
```

Also, Rojo said:

> `ScheduledTasks` is more appropriate. `Dynamic` is for display. You could try `Dynamic[NotebookEvaluate[ "C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\allnotebooks.nb"];
>
>            ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], UpdateInterval -> 15]`